# NoClassDefFoundError when starting MRAppMaster on Hadoop 2.6.0 to 2.7.1 upgrade

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, classpath

Upon updating our application from 2.6.0 to 2.7.1 I've been unable to get our mapper jobs running correctly with the following appearing in the job logs:

```
SEVERE: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:285)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName.<clinit>(KerberosName.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1448)
```

I thought initially this was a classpath issue specifically in our jobs, for which our libs are copied to the distributed cache and then added to the classpath of the job prior to each job being run. A bit of verification confirmed though that all libs are in place and added to the classpath prior to the job being run.

Both `hadoop classpath` and `yarn classpath` reveal that everything under `hadoop/share/hadoop` is on the classpath, which contains the lib (log4j) the class in question belongs to above.

We're a bit out of ideas. The code being executed works perfectly fine on our 2.6.0 branch. What might we be missing?

Comment: Have you found the solution to your problem ? I'm having the exact same issue and no luck so far

Comment: Yes @cheseaux!!! I'll document an answer, but by off chance, did you upgrade without editing/updating your `hadoop/etc/hadoop/container-log4j.properties` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this ended up being a subtle issue where the class in question **was** being provided on the classpath, but when it was initially being loaded it was blowing up as it referenced a null variable, and the subsequent exception/stack trace that would have indicated this was lost somewhere deep in the bowels of Hadoop!

In Hadoop 2.7.x, ContainerLogAppender gained the ability to setContainerLogFile. Unfortunately, if `log4j.appender.CLA.containerLogFile=${hadoop.root.logfile}` and `log4j.appender.CRLA.containerLogFile=${hadoop.root.logfile}` are not set in `hadoop/etc/hadoop/container-log4j.properties`, then this blows up with the NPE. Where as previously it defaulted to "syslog", it now has no default and will happily let you dig yourself a hole. Hence when the classes blow up while being loaded by the classloader, they are in effect removed, and hence why further down the line the job reports `NoClassDefFoundError` as opposed to a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Just ran into this, this fixed it. for search engine juice, you may also get something like `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:317)

        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ContainerLogAppender.activateOptions(ContainerLogAppender.java:53)`, and it can occur in the upgrade to Cloudera CDH 5.8.0 from an earlier edition.

Answer (score 0):

I think that because Hadoop release 2.7.1 release [drops support for JDK6 runtime and works with JDK 7+ only](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/) the issue you are facing might be because of older sl4j jar. Can you try updating the sl4j.jar to a latest version.

Comment: The class at issue isn't an SLF4J, but rather a Log4J class. And this would only be an issue if it were the opposite - e.g. the class/lib were compiled using JDK7 but we were using JDK6. It's perfectly fine (and normal) to use libs that were compiled using older JDK's.